# Merge tags w2 and form-w-2

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I am not sure if the tags [w2](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/w2) and [form-w-2](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-w-2) are the same. If they are Can we merge this.

Else can we have tag wiki to explain the difference.

A synonym may not be required as search for w-2 automatically get form-w-2.

Comment: Which one should be the primary?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I guess the convention is "form-" for other such tags. However there are some question that use w2 as noun. i.e. I am on w2 and etc ... so not sure if having a lable form-w-2 is right?

Comment: English seems to create its own usage. "Fed Ex" is a company name, but is used as a verb to send overnight, presumably with this company. I've seen "I'm a W-2 employee" which uses W-2 as an adjective. Either way, the OP means "I am paid and have my income reported via Form W-2, I am not self employed or an independent contractor."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, they should be merged.

I personally prefer [form-w-2](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-w-2).  [Form W-2 officially](https://www.irs.gov/uac/about-form-w2) has a hyphen in the middle.  Most of the other form tags have "form" in the tag name, and it is nice to be able to type "form" in the [tag searchbox](https://money.stackexchange.com/tags) and see all the form tags appear.

Comment: I've done this now.